# Getting 'Got a segv while executing native code'

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, vidyo

I am working with vidyo SDKs for video calling in Xamarin forms. On upgrading to the latest version I start getting the below error in Xamarin ios application.

It is working fine in the older version 4.1.25.30 and the upgraded version is 20.1.0.9.

when I am calling ConnectToHost method it is throwing the exception and the UI is getting hanged
I am still not able to figure out the root cause of the error,
any idea anyone?

Here are the logs.

```
    The thread 0xd has exited with code 0 (0x0).

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x10a4ee5ac - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x10a4e4824 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x10a4f29d4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/Frameworks/Mono.fram
ework/Mono : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler
    0x18b6f69fc - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
    0x10686db78 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : _ZN16XamarinCallState3selEv
    0x10686c564 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : _ZN16XamarinCallState3selEv
    0x10686af2c - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : _ZN16XamarinCallState3selEv
    0x10686bd3c - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : _ZN16XamarinCallState3selEv
    0x18b6fc738 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18b6f4ba4 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18b6fc6b4 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : <redacted>
    0x106886da4 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5
-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : _ZN16XamarinCallState3selEv
    0x10686be04 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : _ZN16XamarinCallState3selEv
    0x10686c214 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : _ZN16XamarinCallState3selEv
    0x106915cb4 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : _ZN16XamarinCallState3selEv
    0x107191334 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : VidyoVirtualShareManagerSetUserDataNative
    0x107ced83c - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : VidyoVirtualShareManagerSetUserDataNative
    0x1088f99c0 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandM
arkHealth.iOS : VidyoVirtualShareManagerSetUserDataNative
    0x1089024cc - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : VidyoVirtualShareManagerSetUserDataNative
    0x106c232d8 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : VidyoRemoteMicrophoneSetUserDataNative
    0x106c2226c - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : VidyoRemoteMicrophoneSetUserDataNative
    0x106c22694 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : VidyoRemoteMicrophoneSetUserDataNative
    0x106996a5c - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : VidyoCameraControlCapabilitiesDestructNative
    0x106996498 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.a
pp/LandMarkHealth.iOS : VidyoCameraControlCapabilitiesDestructNative
    0x1012b3158 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1010c489c - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1010b16b8 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x10562e118 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1054cad14 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1056073a8 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1056295d0 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1054cad14 - /var/containers/
Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x105606310 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1056478d0 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1016a04ec - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1056194b4 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x10120156c - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1016a04ec - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1011e0654 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1011ee1d0 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x10169fd4c - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1011a9bc0 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1011a9114 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x101c96370 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x10a4f5e18 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_get_runtime_build_info
    0x10a5b1e90 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x10a
5b56f4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_runtime_invoke
    0x100ffcfec - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x100ffccc8 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1ad168338 - /System/Library/Frameworks/PushKit.framework/PushKit : <redacted>
    0x18b524a38 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18b5257d4 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18b4d3008 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18ba78b20 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x18ba73a58 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x18ba72fb4 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    0x18dc7479c - /System/Library/Pr
ivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
    0x1b811ac38 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIApplicationMain
    0x1045dbcf8 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x103d18c30 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x103d18ab4 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x1011be7a4 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x101c96370 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x10a4f5e1
8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_get_runtime_build_info
    0x10a5b1e90 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x10a5b80e8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked
    0x10a4d3820 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_jit_exec
    0x1067ca618 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : xamarin_localized_string_format_9
    0x1010ae654 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/78C49137-E3CD-4D02-8DE5-FE587EAD2533/LandMarkHealth.iOS.app/LandMarkHealth.iOS : 
    0x18b5368e0 - /usr/lib/system/li
bdyld.dylib : <redacted>

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x72):0x62  2020-06-26 10:34:12.831 +00:00: ERROR: VidyoClient: [System thread]: /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_20_1_0_9.build.7uOSFpBWGF/source/SDK/Lmi/VidyoClient/VidyoEndpoint.c:785: CrashHandler_: CrashHandler: 
0x15ccd6b00
```

Comment: Open an issue with Vidyo.

Comment: I have done that

Comment: I have identified that this error is occurring when I am Initializing Scanbot in AppDelegate. On commenting the Scan bot code it is working fine. Any idea anyone?